# How to extract US zip codes and check range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alias

I have a table of addresses with postal codes from the US and Canada. In our system we assign territories based on zip code ranges so I need to extract the US addresses and check whether they are within a given range. The tables look like this:

```
Key             Postalcode
---------------------------
1               58230
2               49034-9731
3               98801
4               M5H 4E7
```

I run a select statement

```
SELECT 
    key, CONVERT(int, LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Postalcode)),5)) AS pcode 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE
    LEFT(Postalcode, 5) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

and the results return the table as expected.

```
Key             Postalcode
--------------------------
1               58230
2               49034
3               98801
```

I then wrap the alias and attempt to check the range.

```
select 
    key, pcode 
from 
    (select 
         key, convert(int, LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(Postalcode)),5)) as pcode  
     from  
         Table 
     where 
         LEFT(Postalcode,5) not like '%[^0-9]%') x
 where 
     x.pcode between 58000 and 59000
```

SQL Server 2008 returns this error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M5H 4' to data type int.

Can someone tell me what is happening? It appears like the select from the alias is doing some scan of the original table and encountering the Canadian postal code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @terry-h , can you mention which database you are using , please? It is obvious but it will be helpful for any future readers. Thanks

Comment: Specifically what is happening, is you're trying to cast a value that isn't a number to a number.  This is happening because your select statement contained a non-number postal code that you're trying to convert to an int.  On a separate, somewhat unrelated note, you'll want to be careful when dealing with post codes as a whole, especially if the data ever starts expanding outside of North America, because there are some countries that plain out don't use postal codes at all (Ireland comes to mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `pcode`, then use:

```
select key, pcode
from (select key,
             (case when postalcode like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                   then cast(left(postalcode, 5) as int)
              end) as pcode
      from t
     ) t
where t.pcode between 58000 and 59000;
```

However, converting to an int is really unnecessary.  You cold just use:

```
select key, left(postalcode, 5)
from table t
where postalcode like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' and
      postalcode between '58000' and '59000';
```

It makes much more sense to treat postal codes as strings rather than numbers.

And, the reason your code doesn't work is because SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` and `where`.  So, it pushes the calculation of `pcode` to before the filtering.  This is a good thing from a performance perspective, but I do consider it a bug.  It is easy enough to work around by using `case` (which does guarantee the order of evaluation of its conditions).